# ActionListener and combo-box issue

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm currently having an issue where I am creating a simple web browser and want to write the url of each page visited. Anyway, when the History combo-box is being filled with the URL's the .addItem function is triggering my action listener. Is there any way around this?

```
   Action Listener: 
   historyList.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    final String url= historyList.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    addressbar.setText(url); //set the address bar to the url 
                    historyArray[historynum] = url; //add the url to the array which contains the history
                    historynum = historynum + 1;    //move one up the history array
                    Display(url);           //display the url
                    backplace = 1;          //reset the amount of backs a user can take 
                    forwardBtn = false;     //not allow the user to go forward again
                }
            }
            );
   }
```

adding URL's from config file to combo:

```
    for (String linehistory : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("config.history"),Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        if (!(linehistory ==null)){
            for (String partHistory : linehistory.split("\\s+")) {
                String historylines = partHistory;
                if( i >6){
                    if (!(partHistory ==null)){
                        historyList.addItem(partHistory);
                    }
                }
                i = i +1;
            }
        }
```

I have noticed this, and I think it may be due to the state of the combo-box being changed, is there a way to change this to onClick? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8nHr.jpg

Comment: Doesn't sound right.  JComboBox documentation says action listeners are invoked when a selection is made, not when items are added.  So it's probably a mistake elsewhere.  Can you create a complete example that runs and reproduces the problem?

Comment: @markspace When I step through the code, when it enters the .addItem it then jumps. I'm not sure how I would do this as its part of a larger project?. The issue gets more confusing as upon running the loop is ran to fill the box with values which work the first time and don't cause the action listener to activate but only when used again it then causes the issue

Comment: You just need to write a small program that reproduces the problem, that's all.

Comment: @markspace I have made an edit to the question does this make a difference? if not I'll remake the issue

Comment: I don't see anything that would make a difference.  Complete code is needed, at least for me.

Comment: ... well maybe not **complete** code as we don't want to see your full program as it will likely contain a lot of code not relevant to the problem, but we'd love to see a **very small** compilable and runnable program that shows the problem to us, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How would I upload this? I don't know how I would make it into a smaller one. I can give you complete code as it's only a pretty small project but I have multiple frames, tool bars, that would be difficult to make into a smaller project. I can see when debugging that it works first time when the action listener isn't active, it's then activated and the next time it's used the code it's classing .additem as an "Action Command = comboBoxChanged" thus triggering the code for action command

Comment: **Again**, no one wants to see the entire project or slog through a bunch of frames, tool bars, etc. Yes it will take effort for you to create a smaller program, but it's effort worthwhile, and effort that you should expend rather than us, since it is your problem and we're volunteers. I can almost guarantee that if you post the entire program or a large bit of code, most of it unrelated to your problem, you risk having this question closed. Please don't even consider doing this.

Comment: I have no idea how to make it into a **very small** program, I would have to rebuild the whole thing and I'm new to this and genuinely don't know how

Comment: `"I have no idea how to make it into a very small program, I would have to rebuild the whole thing ..."` -- and that's exactly what you should do. Create a new small program that only has the problem code in it. We're not forcing you to do this, but if you want a solution here, it's your best way of getting one. And again, I can't stress enough, you don't want to post your whole project or a wall of code. Just create a new small program, one with the essential bits from your main program and try to reproduce your error. You'll learn a lot in the process, so it won't be a waste of time.

Comment: solved the issue, restructured my code so the combo-box loop isn't called again and added the items in a different way and it worked somehow. Thanks anyway for your time guys

Comment: Excellent -- glad that you've solved it. One lesson to get out of this -- in the future, focus on creating small classes that have a single responsibility and are easily testable in isolation. Doing this will make your code **much** easier to debug, or failing that, much easier for us to help with.